# UNION Query Error

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have following two tables(DEPT and EMP):

```
DEPT

DEPTNO,DNAME,LOC

EMP

EMPNO, ENAME,JOB,MGR,HIREDATE,SAL,COMM,DEPTNO
```

I'm executing the following query:
"Use a UNION to display department numbers and names and employee numbers and names. Choose
appropriate column headings and sort it by name in ascending order."

Here is my query:

```
SELECT Deptno, Dname 
FROM DEPT
ORDER BY Dname ASC
UNION
SELECT EMPNO,ENAME 
FROM   EMP
ORDER BY ENAME ASC;
```

I'm wondering why I'm getting the following error:

> UNION
>   * ERROR at line 4: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended.

Could anyone please tell me what's wrong here?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT Deptno AS ID, Dname  AS NAME
FROM DEPT
UNION
SELECT EMPNO  AS ID,ENAME  AS NAME
FROM   EMP
ORDER BY NAME ASC
```

**EDIT**

To display four columns check below query using join

```
SELECT E.EMPNO ,E.ENAME ,D.Deptno , D.Dname 
FROM DEPT D
INNER JOIN 
EMP E ON E.DeptNO = D.DeptNo
ORDER BY E.ENAME ASC
```

Comment: This query is running and producing only ID and NAME columns.

The Deptnp and EMpNo are combined under ID column and Dname and Ename are combined in Name columns which is not desired.
I suppose there should be four columns for this query.

Comment: @AaK: No. Union combines result tables with **identical** columns to one result table with the same column layout. ID and Name in this case.

Comment: @AaK If you need four columns then you should use joins instead of union

Comment: Thanks Marco and sivareddy. Since the question specifically says to use UNION, I'm bound to use UNION in this case. Thanks for clarifying. I'll keep in my mind if I want to have four columns I'll use JOINS. Thanks once again. Appreciated !

Answer (score 0):

Remove `ORDER BY` clause in the first query.

So change to:

```
SELECT Deptno, Dname 
FROM DEPT
UNION
SELECT EMPNO,ENAME 
FROM   EMP
ORDER BY Dept.Dname, Emp.Ename ASC;
```

Should work.